# Promises: How to resolve an unknown amount of promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function that takes in an unknown amount of building id's in an array i.e [4,5] and then  calls a function which returns it's name and description. I don't know how to approach this given that it is an unknown amount. I tried creating a for loop but that led nowhere and I'm completely lost. What you see below is me sending an entire array to a function, but I want to loop through each element and call the function individually

Edit: Thank you everybody for the kind replies. You have been very helpful and supportive

```
function getBuilding(buildingId){
      return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
          Building.getBuilding(buildingId).then((buildingInfo)=>{
              resolve(buildingInfo);
          }); 
      })
}
```

Comment: [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)?

Comment: The whole function in your question is equivalent to `function getBuilding(buildingId){ return Building.getBuilding(buildingId); }`. There is no need to use a Promise constructor there.

Comment: But I call the function an unknown amount of times

Comment: @nodeboi `Promise.all( buildingIdsArray.map( getBuilding ) ).then( buildingInfoArray => { ... } );`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), the promise of `all` will resolve once all the items in the array have also resolved. This then will return a promise with an array of the results where the first item is the first building id result, the second is the second id, and so on.

```js
function getBuilding(ids) {
  let promises = []
  // We will assume `getInfo()` returns a promise that resolves the buildings info
  ids.forEach(id => promises.push(getInfo(id)))
  return Promise.all(promises)
}

function getInfo(id) {
  // Resolves the info after a random amount of time to simulate
  // something that may take some time to execute.
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({id}), Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000)))
}

console.log('Just a moment, calculating data...')
getBuilding([3, 5, 7, 9]).then(results => {
  console.log('building id', results[0].id) // buildingId = 3
  console.log('building id', results[1].id) // buildingId = 5
  console.log('building id', results[2].id) // buildingId = 7
  console.log('building id', results[3].id) // buildingId = 9
})
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for

Comment: If `Building.getInfo` returns a Promise whats the point of the `new Promise` constructor?

Answer (score 3):

The Promise.all() method takes an array of promises and waits till they all resolve.

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
```

Note that if any one of the promises fail Promise.all() will fail.

Comment: buildingId is an array though and can be any size. If it was always had say 2 elements, then I would use promise.all, but what if there is 8 one time then 6 the next

Comment: @nodeboi takes an array of any size

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Promise.all` which takes and `iterable` which in this case can be an array.

Like:

```
function caller( ...promises ) {
    Promise.all( promises ).then( function( value ) {
      console.log( 'all completed' );
    });

}
```

Where promises is basically an array of arguments, take a look at:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments#Description

Answer (score 2):

I think spread operator and `Promise.all`

```
function getInfos(...ids) {
  return Promise.all(ids.map(id => Building.getBuilding(id )));
}

//      can be any number of params
getInfos(id1, id2, id3).then(([info1, info2, info3]) => {
  // do stuff
});
```

I saw in an other comment `buildingId` is array, in that case:

```
const buildingId = [1, 2, 3];
getInfos(...buildingId).then(([info1, info2, info3]) => {
  // do stuff
});
```

or simplified

```
function getInfos(ids) {
  return Promise.all(ids.map(id => Building.getBuilding(id )));
}

const buildingId = [1, 2, 3];
getInfos(buildingId).then(([info1, info2, info3]) => {
  // do stuff
});
```